# To work in a (the) capacity as (of)?

Tags: phrases, phrase-usage

I am confused by the correct usage of "capacity" (noun), especially from the first person.

According to Merriam-Webster the following to usages of [capacity](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/capacity) are OK:

> He worked in *his capacity as judge*.
>
> He worked in *a supervisory capacity*.

Cambridge gives slightly different [guidelines](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/capacity):

> He worked in *his capacity as a judge*.

And Webster's 1913 a [different one](http://www.websters1913.com/words/Capacity) still:

> He worked in *the capacity of a judge*.

---

While this is confusing in and of itself, it's still not clear to me how to use this expression from a first-person perspective. Here are the possibilities I come up with:

"I worked in...":

- ...*my capacity as judge*
- ...*in a capacity as judge*
- ...*my capacity as a judge*
- ...*the capacity of a judge*

Of the above, which wording would be preferred (e.g. for a cover letter)?

Answer (score 3):

"As" is for sentences like this one:

> In my capacity as an ELU participant, I try contribute my point of view via comments rather than answers when the questions aren't well posed.

"Of" is for sentences like this one:

> He passed the bar exam in 2002 and has worked in the capacity of a judge since 2006.

Comment: I don't see the difference.

Comment: [Google 4-grams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in+the+capacity+as%2Cin+his+capacity+as%2Cin+the+capacity+of%2Cin+his+capacity+of&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3) lend support to the theory that 'in the capacity of' is by far the preferred form with the definite article but 'in his/her/my/their/... capacity as' is the preferred form with a possessive determiner.

Answer (score 0):

I would follow the advice of the Cambridge dictionary and use "capacity as". I would only use "capacity of" in other senses of the word (e.g. the capacity of a container, or the capacity of a meeting room).

Most commonly we use "in the capacity as" with a personal pronoun. It is also more straightforward to include an "a" before a profession, even if it may be possible in some/most instances to leave it out. Therefore, the best option is the phrasing "in my capacity as a judge".

Last of all, a better formulation for the whole phrase may be "In my capacity as a judge I...". Any sentence beginning "I worked in my capacity as a judge" will be difficult for the reader to follow.